# How to start iterating through a collection not from the beginning

Tags: java, collections

I want the iteration to skip the first few elements. `elements` is a `List<WebElement>`. I would like to iterate through the list not from the beginning, but starting from somewhere in the middle, how could I do that?

```
for ( WebElement element : elements )
{
      //block of code
}
```

Comment: What is `elements`, a `List<WebElement>`, or just an `Iterable<WebElement>` or even `WebElement[]`?

Comment: If not from the beginning, from what else?

Comment: elements is List<WebElement>.

Comment: @Chiel92 lets say starting from the third element in the list.

Comment: That means you are able to perform a regular for loop. The "foreach" construct is meant to encapsulate iteration through a collection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For many cases where you want to apply *some operation* to a *specific range* of `List`, you can [use `subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

```
for (WebElement element : elements.subList(3, 7)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This also works fine for removing some range:

```
myList.subList(4, 14).clear();
```

Note that `subList` only exists on `List`, so this won't work on a `Set` or other non-List `Collection` objects.

Comment: Your solution meets my requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If `elements` is a List, you could use the listIterator, specifically the method `elements.listIterator(index)`. It will return a list iterator starting at the element at `index`.

E.g:

```
for(ListIterator iter = elements.listIterator(2);iter.hasNext;) {
  WebElement element = (WebElement)iter.next;
  ...
}
```

If `elements` is not a list, you still could use that approach by creating a new list with the contents of your collection.

Answer (score 5):

You can use List.listIterator(int) as in this example

```
    List<WebElement> list = ...
    for(Iterator<WebElement> i = list.listIterator(1); i.hasNext();) {
        WebElement next = i.next();
    }
```

or simply

```
for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
     WebElement e = list.get(i);
}
```

note that #1 is faster with LinkedList and #2 is faster with ArrayList.
There is a special marker interface java.util.RandomAccess to determine which version is more efficient for a given List.

Comment: The second method is slow if the list is not random access (such as a linked list)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use simplest and most straightforward way?

```
int i = 0;
for (WebElement element : elements)
{
      if (/*i++ satisfies some condition*/) {
          //block of code
      }
}
```

Or, more native way: keep track of index in an unenhanced for-loop.

Other way like creating sublist looks fancier, but that will take more time and space.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an arraylist if you want to reference, or make your own, so to speak. This will let you access points by reference (like an array) then you can iterate through with a generic
while(node.hasNext()) {...} to the end.